# Angular orderBy with date string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I'm attempting to order events in my web app by date (in this case 'start' date from my db). I'm running into issues where the dates aren't sorted properly. I believe they are sorting alphanumerically rather than by date because my 'start' field is a string. My question is, how to best convert this field to Date for proper ordering? Relevant code below:

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy:'start'">{{event.city}}</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
angular.module('MainCtrl', []).controller('MainController', function($scope, $routeParams, Events) {

  // pull empty event details from API based on routeParams to get all events
  $scope.id = '';

  Events.get($scope.id).success(function(response) {
      $scope.events = response;
  });
});
```

Sample database object:

```
{
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "54978d87ac1e3caaeee8452c"
  },
  "event": "New Years Eve - Times Square",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": "New York",
  "date": "December 31, 2014",
  "start": "December 31, 2014",
  "end": "January 1, 2015",
  "radius": "400",
  "team_1": "",
  "team_2": "",
  "object_id": "10897094",
  "longitude": "-73.9848931",
  "latitude": "40.7591529",
  "photos": []
}
```

Comment: Convert the field to date object in the controller or service that returns the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a very simple solution. I simply added the following code to my controller inside my `Events.get`:

```
for (var i = 0, max = response.length; i < max; i++) {
        $scope.events[i].start = new Date(response[i].start);
}
```

Comment: Or even shorter `angular.forEach($scope.events, function(event){ event.start = new Date(event.start); });` :)

Comment: Hi Matt, How does it display in browser, actually have a scenario where the date is displayed as "31AUG2016 21:26:11" and want to do and ascending and descending order, could you help the same.. thanks.

Comment: @DelliKilari in that case you'd want to set a new attribute to the object, say `event.preformattedDate`, and `orderBy:preformattedDate` instead.